# PyTorch Autoregressive Model Commands

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, autoregressive-models

In PyTorch Autoregressive Model, in below line command, why we need to put -N?
as I checked when we are using N we get the same result. so, why using minus is necessary?
X_train=torch.from_numpy(X[:-N//2].astype(np.float32))

X_train=torch.from_numpy(X[:-N//2].astype(np.float32))
above is the command mentioned in PyTorch AutoRegressive Model,
but why minus N?